# Can token string be retrieved from Firebase onCall function context?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Firebase [onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) functions are passed a pre-validated auth context, which implements the [functions.https.CallableContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https.html#.CallableContext) interface.

I am trying to figure out a way to get the encoded JWT in the function scope so that i can use it for additional services (i.e. when using Google auth provider, the token can be used for various apis if the proper scopes are added in the client generating the token).

Is there any way to get the encoded token from the context passed to the function? or will I have to use standard [onRequest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) functions (which will require a lot of boilerplate...

Comment: I'd just file a feature request for it.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: i will, do you have any suggestions in the meantime?

Comment: If it's not documented for callables, then it's likely not possible without doing it yourself.